# If $U=XW$, is it possible to calculate $Z^\top X$, where $Z=\operatorname{null}(U^\top)$, knowing only $X^\top X$ and $W$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a matrix $U$ of size $d \times m$ and $X$ of size $d \times n$ and $W$ of size $n \times m$, it is given that: $$U = X W$$

How can I calculate $Z^{\top} X$ where $Z = \operatorname{null}(U^{\top})$ while only knowing $X^{\top}X$ and $W$?

(I define $\operatorname{null}(A)$ to be the matrix $C$ such that $\operatorname{norm}(AC)$ is small and $C^{\top} C = I$, meaning an orthonormal basis for the null space of $A$.)

Comment: "norm(AC) is small"?

Comment: I  was just taking it from Matlab's definition, "Z = null(A) is an orthonormal basis for the null space of A obtained
    from the singular value decomposition.  That is,  A*Z has negligible
    elements, size(Z,2) is the nullity of A, and Z'*Z = I." It just means finding the null space basis.